# How to combine and group arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm getting values and I want to put them into an array:

```
    var values = {25,23,21}
    var unit = {PCS,KG,PCS}
```

I want it to be like this when I put them in an array

```
    array = {25:PCS,23:KG,21:PCS}
```

and group and add them depending on the unit so the final result will be something like this

```
    totalval = {46:PCS,23:KG}
```

I can only put those values into separate arrays but I don't know how can I combine and group them..

Comment: these are objects, not arrays.

Comment: oh sorry, as I'm new when it comes to this kind of problem..

Comment: looking at this question it appears you actually want arrays, that form into one object. You also can't have numbers as property names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/wyh5a2h2/

I went through reorganizing your code so it makes a bit of sense and came up with this: Hopefully it suits what you are attempting to do:

```
var items = [
    {value: 25, unit: 'PCS'},
    {value: 23, unit: 'KG'},
    {value: 21, unit: 'PCS'},
]

var numPCS = 0, numKG = 0;
var result = [];

items.forEach(function(elem, index) {
    if(elem.unit==='PCS') {
        numPCS+=elem.value;
    }
    if(elem.unit==='KG') {
        numKG+=elem.value;
    }
});

result.push({value: numPCS, unit: 'PCS'});
result.push({value: numKG, unit: 'KG'});

console.log(result);
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: That's pretty much it.  I simplified your fiddle a bit and made it generic [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wyh5a2h2/1/)

Comment: It works great! But what if my unit value is dynamic? How can I still group them??

Comment: @James Yeah I wasn't really sure what the OP wanted. It was a mixture of arrays and objects that didn't make sense, so I just did what I thought looked similar...

Comment: @user2119308 If the unit is dynamic, put the units in an array, and then iterate through them, while comparing them...

Answer (score 1):

you will have to create objects first and then put them into an array

```
 var obj1 =  {
     value: 25,
     unit: "PCS"   
 };

 ...

 var array = [ obj1, obj2, obj3, ... ];
```

then aggregate them accordingly

Comment: Did I just see you name an object `array` ?!?!?!

Comment: @MaxMastalerz `array` is also object, it's not primitive data type. Nevertheless the example is wrong: it should either use the `object` keys or the `array` notation.

Comment: I know an array is an object, but it's not useful to call it that. Just call it array. plzzzzz

Comment: Devil's advocate: An object in javascript *is* technically an associative array. :-)

Comment: Thank you Gertrude Stein :P

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = [25, 23, 21],
    unit = ['PCS', 'KG', 'PCS'],
    result = {},
    tmpval = {},
    totalval = {};

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    result[values[i]] = unit[i];
    tmpval[unit[i]] || (tmpval[unit[i]] = 0);
    tmpval[unit[i]] += values[i];
}

for (var i in tmpval) {
    totalval[tmpval[i]] = i;
}

// result: { '21': 'PCS', '23': 'KG', '25': 'PCS' }
// totalval: { '23': 'KG', '46': 'PCS' }
```